# Python tkinter GUI application becomes non responsive

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multithreading

I have a tkinter python application as follows:

```
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.ttk import *
    from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
    from tkinter import ttk
    import tkinter as tk
    import tkinter.ttk, threading
    tkk = Tk()
    tkk.title("sample")
    tkk.geometry('350x200')
    number= tk.StringVar()  
    choice= Combobox(tkk, width=12, textvariable=number)  
    choice.grid(column=0,row=1) 
    class progress():
        def __init__(self, parent):
                self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(tkk, orient = HORIZONTAL, mode = 'indeterminate')
                self.t = threading.Thread()
                self.t.__init__(target = self.progressbar.start, args = ())
                self.progressbar.grid(row=4,columnspan=6,sticky=W+E,padx=(40,10))
                self.t.start()

        def end(self):

                self.progressbar.stop()
                self.t.join()
    def click(): 
        action.configure(text="chosen case is : "+ selected.get()) 
        print("clicked button is :")

        id = 0
        while id < 10:
            progress(tkk)
            id+=1
        else:
            new=progress(tkk)
            new.end()        

    action = ttk.Button(tkk, text="Click", command=click)
    action.grid(column=1,row=1)

    selected= ttk.Combobox(tkk, width=12, textvariable=number)  
    selected['values']=('a','b','c','d')
    selected.grid(column=0,row=1)  
    selected.current() 
    tkk.mainloop()
```

The output is as:

[image]

Now when I select an element from drop down and hit click button I should I get progress bar starting if id < 10 else progress bar is stoped.
So when the progress bar is stopped the output window becomes non responsive and it crashes. I am starting the progress within a thread. 
Not getting why it becomes non responsive when progress bar is stopped.

Comment: In a very general way, it looks like you really don't know what you are doing here. You import ttk and tkinter several times, you create comboboxes on top of each other and then you have a while-loop which creates ten progress bars but does not save any references to any of them. I'd recommend you to create each of your elements (combobox, button, progress bar) each in it's own test application and make sure that you understand them, and then put them all together. When it works you can begin studying threading. Yeah; and you use the reserved word `id` as a variable name...

Comment: `from tkinter import ttk` and `tkk = Tk()`... You are correct, it is surprising that it freezes, it should probably explode instead!